# Efficient replacement of conditional nested Do over elements of a matrix

Tags: programming, matrix

I have two matrices like these:

```
m1=Table[Random[],{i,10},{j,10}]

m2=Table[Random[],{i,10},{j,10}]
```

I want to create a new matrix in which its main diagonal elements are zero and off-diagonals are determined based on

```
Min(m1[[i,j]],m2[[i,j]])
```

I came up with this `Do` loop:

```
newm=ConstantArray[0,{10,10}];
Do[
Do[
If[m1[[i,j]]<m2[[i,j]],newm[[i,j]]=m1[[i,j]],newm[[i,j]]=m2[[i,j]]],
{j,10}],
{i,10}]
```

What is the better way for doing this and avoiding `Do` loops?Is it possible to use `Map` and `Which`?

Comment: You can do `ReplacePart[
 MapThread[Min[{#1, #2}] &, {m1, m2}, 2], {i_, i_} -> 0]`.

Comment: a possibility : `Table[If[i === j, 0, Min[m1[[i, j]], m2[[i, j]]]], {i, 10}, {j, 10}]`

Answer (score 5):

If I am understanding you:

```
SeedRandom[1];

m1 = RandomReal[1, {5, 5}];
m2 = RandomReal[1, {5, 5}];

arrayMin = Function[Null, Min[##], Listable];
arrayMin[m1, m2] (1 - IdentityMatrix[5]) // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 0.11142 & 0.59326 & 0.187803 & 0.169013 \\
 0.0657388 & 0 & 0.0118355 & 0.316876 & 0.700474 \\
 0.011978 & 0.391276 & 0 & 0.247495 & 0.727517 \\
 0.790566 & 0.263269 & 0.297514 & 0 & 0.0553108 \\
 0.481571 & 0.128821 & 0.203011 & 0.544772 & 0
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: Nice, but I note that your solution takes 30% more time than mine ;-P Funny thing, if I combine half of your solution with half of mine the result performs best: `(1 - IdentityMatrix[10]) MapThread[Min, {m1, m2}, 2]`

Comment: ..although for larger matrices the `SparseArray` version is again better.

Comment: @Sjoerd I made no attempt to optimize this.  Instead I tried to provide a simple yet practical method.  +1 on yours too.

Answer (score 5):

```
SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 0, {_, _} -> 1}, {10, 10}] MapThread[Min, {m1, m2}, 2]
```

Comment: A shorter and slightly faster way to define the SparseArray: `SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> 0, {10, 10}, 1]`

Comment: Sjoerd, the question is now undeleted.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you might want to write

```
m1 = RandomReal[1, {10, 10}]
m2 = RandomReal[1, {10, 10}]
```

Which should be a lot faster and does not make use of the "outdated" `Random[]`.

Procedural code is easily compilable! You could do this (suboptimal)

```
cfu =
  Compile[
   {{m1, _Real, 2}, {m2, _Real, 2}, {nnnn, _Integer}},
   Block[
    {newm}
    ,
    newm = ConstantArray[0., {nnnn, nnnn}];
    Do[
     Do[
      If[
       i != j
       ,
       If[
        m1[[i, j]] < m2[[i, j]]
        ,
        newm[[i, j]] = m1[[i, j]]
        ,
        newm[[i, j]] = m2[[i, j]]
        ]

       ]
      ,
      {j, nnnn}
      ]
     ,
     {i, nnnn}

     ];
    newm
    ]
   ,
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];
```

One little issue with this is that it you only need to use one Do. In your code, you could write.

```
Do[
 If[m1[[i, j]] < m2[[i, j]], newm[[i, j]] = m1[[i, j]], 
  newm[[i, j]] = m2[[i, j]]]
 ,
 {i, 10},
 {j, 10}
 ]
```

The main improvement we can make however is to use `Table` instead of `Do` (thanks to Andre). This is both better in the uncompiled as in the compiled case. The compiled function Andre suggested is

```
cfu3 =
 Compile[
  {{m1, _Real, 2}, {m2, _Real, 2}, {nnnn, _Integer}},
  Table[
   If[i === j, 0.,
    Min[m1[[i, j]], m2[[i, j]]]
    ]
   ,
   {i, nnnn}, {j, nnnn}
   ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C"
  ]
```

**Comparison with other answers**

```
mmmm = 1*^3;
arrayMin = Function[Null, Min[##], Listable];

(res1 = cfu[m1, m2, mmmm]) // Timing // First
(res5 = cfu3[m1, m2, mmmm]) // Timing // First
(res3 = arrayMin[m1, m2] (1 - IdentityMatrix[mmmm])) // 
  Timing // First
(res4 = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 0, {_, _} -> 1}, {mmmm, 
       mmmm}] MapThread[Min, {m1, m2}, 2]) // Timing // First
```

> 0.066221 (Me)
>  
>   0.033331 (Andre)
>   1.257168 (Mr.Wizard)
>   0.882195 (Sjoerd)

```
res1 === res2 === res3 === res4
```

> True

Comment: At least as fast as `cfu2`, there is :`cfu3 = Compile[{{m1, _Real, 2}, {m2, _Real, 2}, {nnnn, _Integer}}, Table[If[i === j, 0., Min[m1[[i, j]], m2[[i, j]]]], {i, nnnn}, {j, nnnn}], CompilationTarget -> "C"];`

Comment: @andre ah if that is true then I am really glad. I thought MMA would not be able to figure out that table would be a tensor of integers. If you tested the timings, please tell me. Otherwise I will probably test it myself.

Comment: "tensor of integers" ? I don't understand.    
   I have quickly tested the timing. Cfu3 is between 1 and 3 times faster than cfu2. It depends on the run. –  andre 13 mins ago

Comment: @andre ah I guess I meant reals, huh? :P. Thanks for testing the timings!

Comment: @andre I absorbed your comment in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A fast method without `Compile`:

```
n = 10;
m1 = RandomReal[1, {n, n}];
m2 = RandomReal[1, {n, n}];

SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> 0, {n, n}, 1] (# m1 + (1 - #) m2) &@UnitStep[m2 - m1]
```

Its speed is comparable to compiled solutions because it uses packed arrays.

Comment: I tried this same `UnitStep` method myself but in version 7 is it not faster than `MapThread[Min, {m1, m2}, 2]`.  How are the timings in v9?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard For `n=1000` it takes about 0.16 sec on my old laptop with v9 and 0.9 sec on university server with v6 (latter unpack arrays). I don't have an access to v7, but I think it unpack arrays too.